# Dynamically generating a reify clause using macros

Tags: clojure, reify

I am trying to wrap an implementation and dynamically generate the reify clause for all the interfaces the wrapped object implements.

For example:

I want to generate:

```
(reify
  BaseInterface
    (fee [_] (custom-operation wrapped))
    (foo [_] (.foo wrapped)))
```

or

```
(reify
  BaseInterface
    (fee [_] (custom-operation wrapped))
    (foo [_] (.foo wrapped))
  AnotherInterface
    (bar [_] (.bar wrapped)))
```

depending on whether `wrapped` implements only `BaseInterface` or both `BaseInterface` and `AnotherInterface`.

I tried something like the following, but it fails as the macro is evaluated at compile time and my second argument (the `cond->` expression) doesn't have its runtime value:

```
(defmacro add-interface-implementations
  "Adds additional interface implementations to a reify expression.
   This is useful to create a reify expression dynamically without introducing if-else branching."
  [reify-expr interface->methods]
  (reduce
    (fn [expr# entry#]
      (println "expr#" expr#)
      (println "entry#" entry#)
      (let [[interface# body#] entry#]
        (cons
          (first expr#)
          (cons interface#
                (reduce
                  (fn [e# m#]
                    (cons m# e#))
                  (rest expr#)
                  body#)))))
    reify-expr
    interface->methods))

(add-interface-implementations
  (reify
    BaseInterface
      (fee [_] (custom-operation wrapped))
      (foo [_] (.foo wrapped)))
  (cond-> {}
    (instance? AnotherInterface foo)
    (assoc AnotherInterface [(bar [_] (.bar wrapped))])))
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm trying. I want avoid the if-else branching as it leads to combinatorial explosion as soon as I have more interfaces.

Comment: You could pass in a list of possible interfaces, then use `(isa? child parent)` in a loop to keep only the desired ones.  Then, construct the `reify` command.  However, since you don't have `wrapped` or construct the `reify` command until runtime, I think you'll have to use `eval`.  Probably a bad sign.  Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: I'm creating a wrapper for an object to override certain methods. To preserve the same behavior I need to implement all the interfaces the wrapped object implements.

Comment: But it seems you would have to know in advance which methods you're overridding, right? The use-case may be clearer with a more realistic example target instead of `wrapped`.

Comment: I updated the example with a `fee` method that is overridden. The other methods just need to be delegated to based on whatever interface `wrapped` implements.